# Numpy import error in OSGeo4W Shell

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, osgeo4w, windows-10

I and my colleagues are running into a very frustrating Python import error while using the OSGeo4W Shell. Any time we attempt to use gdal_calc in a Python script, we get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\Scripts\gdal_calc.py", line 51, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

The script we're using works fine in Cygwin on multiple machines, so we know that it's not the script itself, but rather something to do with our OSGEO installations. I have installed and uninstalled numpy in my OSGEO4W64 Python2.7 installation numerous times, both using

`pip install --update`

and using Gohlke's pre-compiled Numpy+MKL binary wheel. My numpy and scipy package installations have all been the correct bit type for my Python installation (64 bit).
Oddly enough, I can import numpy without issue when I call it directly in the OSGeo4W shell.

While I've seen numerous potential solutions for this error online, they almost universally apply to Anaconda installations, and I have no idea how to apply them to OSGEO4W.

A few things about my system:
I'm running Win10 64bit, with the Python2.7 installation that came with OSGEO. My OSGEO and QGIS installs are up to date. For reasons beyond my control, I cannot switch to using Python 3.x, and I do not have Administrative access to my computer without a call to the company Helpdesk, so I generally cannot set my own Python environment paths. There is also another installation of Python2.7 on my computer courtesy of ArcGIS.

Comment: can you please describe the steps for invoking your script?

Comment: My script is contained within a python file, so I just use
>>python MyScript.py

Comment: Within the script itself, after 
`import numpy
from OSGEO import gdal`
The code is 
`cmd2 = 'gdal_calc.py  -A {0} --calc="-9999*(logical_or(A>10000,A<-1000)) + A*(logical_and(A<=10000,A>=-1000))" --NoDataValue=-9999  --outfile={1}'.format(out,out2)
    os.system(cmd2)`

Comment: when you do `python -vv script_name.py` to verify which python you are actually using. you will see references in the output. It feels like you environments are mixed up for some reason or another .

Comment: @Nickves - I've run it with `python -vv myscript.py` and I'm not entirely sure what to make of the output. I think everything is coming from the correct directory, but I'm not sure. It "tried" a lot of different places when it was searching for numpy.

Comment: If qgis loads its not a numpy/python problem. Most likely somewhere something overlaps with the system python (esris in this case). In your osgeo4w/bin there should be a `py2_env.bat` file, which uncouples your python from the system's and prepares it to work with the files in your osgeo4w enviroment. Try to run that file and see what happens. I am sorry if I can't give more help than that :(